# Changing MainWindow background color WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, dialog

I am trying to change the background color of the MainWindow using a dialogbox called EditColorDialog. The dialogbox can read the current background color of the main window just fine but I can't seem to get it to change that color.

```
public partial class EditColorDialog : Window
{
    ColorDialog colorPicker = new ColorDialog();  //this is a colorpicker
    MainWindow mw = new MainWindow();

    public ColorDialog()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        rect.Fill = mw.background;  //reads the color off the main window
    }

    private void rect_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        colorPicker.Owner = this;
        if ((bool)colorPicker.ShowDialog())
        {
            //selects new color from colorpicker
            rect.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(colorPicker.SelectedColor);
        }
    }

    private void OkButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        mw.background = rect.Fill;
        this.Close(); 
    }
}
```

I am using this property in the main window code

```
public Brush background
{
    get { return main_window.Background; }
    set { main_window.Background = value; }   
}
```

Comment: [Capitalization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043.aspx)?

Comment: In which part? I am using a property called "background".

Comment: Properties are "supposed to" be in PascalCase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create a new MainWindow every time you create such a dialog. Not a good idea.

If anything you should set the [`Application.MainWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.mainwindow.aspx) on application startup. Then set the reference like this:

```
MainWindow mw = (MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow;
```

and just use `nw.Background`, that property of yours seems like a non-static wrapper for a static call. Doing it this way you already have the main window.

Answer (score 1):

Why does you EditColorDialog contains another **new** MainWindow? I guess you want a reference to the existing MainWindow which opens the EditColorDialog not a new one.Also i guess thats what H.B. meant, is you have a property **b**ackground, but your MainWindow already contains a Property called **B**ackground notice the uppercase 'B'. When closing the Dialog you can now set the Background property in your passed MainWindow.

Comment: Guess I need to do a bit of reading on properties. Thanks for your response.